# Movie about a cursed coat

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw an old black and white film about a coat or jacket that was cursed or maybe those who wore it just had bad luck.  I didn't see the beginning but I started in where several bank robbers finished successfully robbing a bank (I think), got away from the police by hopping in a small plane.

A fight ensues where the jacket, which was filled with cash, falls from the plane and into a poor black farming community.  The farmer who finds it takes the coat to the local pastor/leader where they distribute the cash to those who prayed for something (making a big distinction from those who 'prayed' vs those who 'wished').

Comment: Is the current answer correct?

Answer (score 2):

[Tales of Manhattan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_Manhattan) based on the Mexican novel *Story of a Tailcoat*.
(1942) [IMDB link](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0035415/)

It's an anthology film with multiple short stories following the bad luck people have with this coat. The scenes you describe are part of the final story in the film:

> The topcoat ends up in a second-hand shop, has an adventure with a tale featured W. C. Fields, Phil Silvers and Margaret Dumont [see below]; where it is stolen by a thief (J. Carrol Naish). He wears it to get into an upscale illegal gambling parlor to rob the patrons. In his escape by plane, the jacket catches on fire and the panicked thief throws it out, with $43,000 of loot in the pockets. It lands by Luke (Paul Robeson) and Esther (Ethel Waters), a poor black couple. They take it to their minister (Eddie Anderson), and they decide to give to their congregation to buy whatever they have prayed for. An old farmer (George Reed) tells Luke that the only thing he prayed for is a scarecrow, so Luke gives him the now ragged jacket to make one.

The film is indeed in black and white, as seen in this scene:

Edit: Found a [full version](https://youtu.be/frb18wac_YA?t=6418) of the film timestamped at the plane.